# Removing second record for the same ID

Tags: stata, multiple-records

I have a dataset in Stata in which an ID can have a maximum of two different records. I am trying to restrict my dataset so that the second record is removed if the result for test A is positive. I have provided an example of a sample dataset below. In my desired output I would like to keep both records for ID 1, the first record for ID 2 (test A record), and the record for ID 3 and ID 4.

```
      ID    |      Test Type  Result    
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          A       -ve       
          1 |          B       +ve      
          2 |          A       +ve       
          2 |          B       +ve     
          3 |          A       +ve 
          4 |          A       -ve  
------------+-----------------------------------
```

Currently my dataset is sorted by ID, but I am unable to figure out how to restrict the dataset based on my desired criteria described above.

Comment: Please note: naming software in the title is not customary (a Stack Overflow convention); the correct spelling is Stata.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id str1 test_type str3 result
1 "A" "-ve"
1 "B" "+ve"
2 "A" "+ve"
2 "B" "+ve"
3 "A" "+ve"
4 "A" "-ve"
end

bysort id (test_type) : drop if _n > 1 & result[1] == "+ve"


. list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------+
     | id   test_t~e   result |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  1          A      -ve |
  2. |  1          B      +ve |
     |------------------------|
  3. |  2          A      +ve |
     |------------------------|
  4. |  3          A      +ve |
     |------------------------|
  5. |  4          A      -ve |
     +------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dataset which has only ID and Test Type A's result.

Merge the new dataset with original data, then drop observations in which result_a is positive and Test Type is B.

I haven't tested the code because I don't have Stata on my pc, but this should work.

```
preserve
keep if TestType == "A"
keep ID Result
ren Result Result_a
save a.dta, replace
restore

merge m:1 ID using a.dta

drop if Result_a == "+ve" & TestType == "B"
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily elaborate. One command will do it if I understand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
by ID: gen aux1=_n
bys ID Result: gen aux2=_N
drop if aux1!=1&aux2!=1&Result=="+ve"
```

Edit based on comments.